# странности sublime text3

Tags: vue.js, sublime-text-3, плагин

Плагин javascript Для sublime text3 очень странно реагирует на слово `default`.Он подчеркивает js тэг как будто там есть ошибка,конечно все работает прекрасно,но это очень раздражает и бесит.Подскажите как это исправить.Если что у название темы для редактора "1337 Color scheme" и я работаю с vue.Мне было бы удобно если бы

> template

можно было ставить после тэга скрипта.Если кто знает как это исправить помогите!
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте просто правильную подсветку синтаксиса - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vue%20Syntax%20Highlight